# How to draw a cardinal line on top of a image in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, python-imaging-library

I want to draw a cardinal line on top of an image. At the moment I use ImageDraw by Pillow which works fine for a normal linear line. But I don't find any possibility to draw a cardinal line like in [d3](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveCardinal). Does anybody know a way to make this possible in Python?

Comment: In computer graphics, curves are usually drawn as series of short linear lines that approximate the shape of the curve within some tolerance, so you could do something like that using `ImageDraw` — if you can iteratively compute coordinates that trace out the curve you want to represent.

Comment: what is a cardinal line?

Comment: @martineau so I have to write this myself. I was hoping there is a method like in d3.

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting you're going to have to write it yourself.